# Block comments on my Question, in favor of chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

Some times I post a question and I am getting long discussions in comments. I prefer to have them in a chat.

So as a question poster, I want to block the comments in favor of chat. So if some one have some thing to ask me, he will do it in a chat.

Comment: So, as a question poster, I don't want any comments. At all. So I block them. And as a new user, with 1 rep, I can't participate in chat.

Comment: How would *other* users be able to see that chat?

Comment: If the notifications is what bothering you so much, you can ask to disassociate the question from your account. Otherwise, really no point blocking comments like this.

Comment: @Oded That not what I meant. I do not want to block the comment, but occasionally replace it with chat. As far for new users, they can't comment any way.

Comment: @Arjan it will be linked in the bottom of the question. Instead of comments.

Comment: At least providing a link to the question's chat would be an improvement over the current *"avoid discussions, do you want to take this to chat"*. I never understood that, as I *think* its result would be some private chat between those who were commenting so far, not accessible to whoever came in late (?). (That said, I rarely use chat, but still feel that comments might holds precious information, even if only valuable for a limited time.)

Comment: @Arjan there's no such thing private room, everyone can see any room, given the link, but it's possible to limit a room so that only authorized users can write.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, curious: are such links shown on a question, when comments have been moved to chat? I never ever clicked the link that suggested me to move a discussion. But assuming others did click: I don't recall seeing links to the resulting chats. (Also, like I said, I feel comments are part of the question, and don't see why they should be taken to chat to start with—but of course *my* comments are far more relevant than those of many others. `;-)`)

Comment: As an aside: I don't feel that on Stack Exchange sites a question is ever *truly* yours. All questions should be useful for (possible) future visitors too. Hence, I don't think that a question asker is the one to decide on favoring chat over comments?

Comment: @Arjan I think once a user click that link, all comments are moved to chat i.e. deleted from the question. This is meant to replace a common scenario of comments chat e.g. "add X" --> "added, getting error Y" --> "do Z" --> "done, now A isn't working" etc etc.

Comment: Ideally, if the case is resolved in chat the OP or the helper would get back and post an answer summarizing that they did.

Comment: I wish I could push you all to chat guys, this is exactly what I am talking about ;)

Comment: This is also what I'm talking about, @Ilya: without a visible indicator that something is going on in chat, people might miss out on relevant information. Also, such indicator might need to tell if *new* chat messages were added lately? I know the SE team might prefer chat, but I like comments!

Comment: @Arjan Chat provide you with more futures than comments.

Comment: If you pushed this to chat, you wouldn't get many of the comments you will get here, and people would come here thinking there's no activity. And Chat does not provide more 'futures'; chatrooms are automatically deleted when inactive. Comments have to be manually deleted.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato Chats have multi-taging, chats have stars, chats have online status and more... I agree with you about activity, but than you can use chat preview, with read more option

Comment: And you'd still lose me and many others

Comment: Sometimes, comments aren't intended for the OP, but rather for other people who come to the post.  This is especially true for answers - `This answer, while it works and is accepted and up voted is seriously flawed and will open several security holes in your application.` should not be in a chat room but instead clearly on the post.  **Furthermore** chat rooms are not eternal and [automated scripts](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) may delete a low activity room within a week (or freeze slightly more active rooms in two weeks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are an awful lot of folks who don't want to use chat. We should respect that.

Comment: Yes we should... But do we have to? ;)